# Correct association for a status of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

So I have two models - `Status` and `Post`.

A status can either be: `Empty`, `Half`, or `Full`.

Each `post` can only have 1 status at any one time, i.e. a post can only be either `empty` or `half`, etc. It has to be one of the 3.

However, a status can have many posts. So the `Empty` status may have 20 posts.

What is the best way to approach this, from an associations perspective?

I was initially thinking that a `Post` has_one `Status`. But the issue with that, is that the `Status` would have to `belong_to` a `Post`.

So right now, I have it as:

```
Status   has_many :posts
Post   belongs_to :status, counter_cache: true
```

But whenever I want to assign a status to a post, I have to do it backways and it feels weird.

i.e. I have to do something like:

```
> g = Post.second
  Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
 => #<Post id: 19, title: "10PP gives you 1 on 1", photo: "1-on-1-Icon.jpg", body: "10PP gives you the real one on one attention you c...", created_at: "2014-08-30 10:48:18", updated_at: "2014-08-30 10:48:18", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status_id: nil> 
2.1.1p76 :010 > half = Status.second
  Status Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "statuses".* FROM "statuses"   ORDER BY "statuses"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
 => #<Status id: 2, name: "half", created_at: "2014-08-28 08:04:42", updated_at: "2014-08-28 08:04:42", posts_count: nil> 
2.1.1p76 :011 > half.posts << g
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "status_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "posts"."id" = 19  [["status_id", 2], ["updated_at", "2014-08-30 11:37:16.121245"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "statuses" SET "posts_count" = COALESCE("posts_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "statuses"."id" = 2
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
  Post Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."status_id" = $1  [["status_id", 2]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Post id: 19, title: "10PP gives you 1 on 1", photo: "1-on-1-Icon.jpg", body: "10PP gives you the real one on one attention you c...", created_at: "2014-08-30 10:48:18", updated_at: "2014-08-30 11:37:16", user_id: 1, ancestry: nil, file: nil, status_id: 2>]>
```

I would rather be going the other way, i.e. assigning a status to the post.

I feel like this is not the best way to do it, but not sure how else to tackle it.

Also, how would I tackle the `PostsController#Create`?

Right now, I have just:

```
@post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
```

Which doesn't assign the correct Status object to the current post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try other way with using `enum` http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-enums

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :empty, :half, :full ]
end

Post.full
Post.first.empty?
```

Comment: of course it is, because it is in the same record, no relations, just one `status` field (even not string just int)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I then find out how many posts have a status of `:half` for instance?

Comment: the simplest way could be `Post.half.size` or something like: `Post.where(status: Post.statuses[:half])`